# Is throttling limit for App id or platform id?

Tags: android, ios, microsoft-graph-api

We have application on iOS and Android platform which uses Microsoft graph API (like email client for end users). We have configured both the application(iOS and Android) under "Home -> application -> (Manage)Authentication (side menu) -> Platform configuration" on same "application(client) id".

Microsoft Graph throttling guidance - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling

For throttling calculation, will it applies for each separate platform (10,000 for iOS and  10,000 for Android per 10 min) or to the "application(client) id"?

Comment: Are you talking about the "Outlook service limits"? *"Outlook service limits are evaluated for each app ID and mailbox combination. In other words, the limits described apply to a specific app accessing a specific mailbox (user or group). If an application exceeds the limit in one mailbox, it does not affect the ability to access another mailbox."*

Comment: Yes, I am talking about "Outlook service limits", so here is "app ID" refers to "application(client) id" which contain iOS and Android platform configured?

Comment: Microsoft Graph throttling Outlook service limits are applicable to the given application id/app id that you registered (which's making the Graph API calls) + the given mailbox. It's not related to ios/andorid, nor its mentioned in the document either.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph throttling Outlook service limits are applicable to the given application id/app id that you registered (which's making the Graph API calls) + the given mailbox. It's not related to ios/andorid, nor its mentioned in the document either.